# ogr2ogr conversion between from shapefile to MBtiles not working as intended

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, osgeo4w, mbtiles

I am trying to convert a shapefile to MBTiles format using ogr2ogr and have been running this script in the OSGEO4W command line

```
ogr2ogr -f MBTILES -dsco MINZOOM=10 -dsco MAXZOOM target.mbtiles C:\users\myself\path_to_shp\source.shp
```

Yet I get this error when I run this command

```
ERROR 1: sqlite3_exec(PRAGMA page_size = 4096;PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF;PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY;CREATE TABLE temp(z INTEGER, x INTEGER, y INTEGER, layer TEXT, idx INTEGER, feature BLOB, geomtype INTEGER, area_or_length DOUBLE);CREATE INDEX temp_index ON temp (z, x, y, layer, idx);) failed:
ERROR 1: MVT driver failed to create target.mbtiles
```

This is my first attempt to use ogr2ogr and I am wondering if it is something simple I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem with command. I didn't supply a proper path to where the MBtiles output should go. I also did not set a value for the MAXZOOM parameter.

The following command worked for me.

```
ogr2ogr -f MBTILES -dsco MINZOOM=10 -dsco MAXZOOM=22 C:\users\myself\path_to_output\target.mbtiles C:\users\myself\path_to_shp\source.shp
```